# Unable to adjust position and text (multi-line) of right side legend in D3js Donut chart

Tags: d3.js, charts, data-visualization, angular7

Hi I am trying to implement d3js donut chart in my angular 7 application. Here is the stackblitz link for the same :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-with-d3js-charts-cne1eb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Current output which I am getting:

[image]

I am trying to adjust right side's legend position like this :

[image]

1. right side legend needs to be vertically aligned properly
2. Each square color box needs to circle
3. Legend text should be multi-line.

I am unable to achieve this. Can anyone help me out with this ?

Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the fixed code in the snippet below:

```js
var w = 583,
      h = 500,
      r = 150,
      inner = 180 / 2,
      color = d3
        .scaleOrdinal()
        .range([
          "rgb(3,17,142)",
          "rgb(19,37,180)",
          "rgb(37,58,217)",
          "rgb(55,78,255)",
          "rgb(94,113,255)",
          "rgb(133,147,254)",
          "rgb(210,215,252)",
        ]),
      margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 100 };

    var data = [
      { label: "Received", value: 194 },
      { label: "Allocated", value: 567 },
      { label: "In Progress", value: 1314 },
      { label: "Cancelled", value: 793 },
      { label: "Returned", value: 1929 },
      { label: "Hold", value: 1383 },
      { label: "Rejected", value: 2 },
    ];

    var total = d3.sum(data, function (d) {
      return d3.sum(d3.values(d));
    });

    var svg = d3
      .select("#chart-1")
      .append("div")
      .classed("svg-container", true) //container class to make it responsive
      .append("svg") // Place the chart in 'pie-chart-div'
      .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
      .attr("viewBox", "0 0 600 500")
      .classed("svg-content-responsive", true)
      .attr("width", "100%")
      .attr("height", "100%");
    var vis = svg
      .data([data])
      .attr("width", "100%")
      .attr("height", "100%")
      .attr("viewBox", -w / 2 + " " + -h / 2 + " " + w + " " + h)
      .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin");

    var textTop = vis
        .append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("class", "textTop")
        .text("Total Orders")
        .attr("fill", "rgb(112,112,112)")
        .attr("y", -10),
      textBottom = vis
        .append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("fill", "rgb(112,112,112)")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("class", "textBottom")
        .text(total.toFixed(2) + "m")
        .attr("y", 10);

    var arc = d3.arc().innerRadius(inner).outerRadius(r);

    var arcOver = d3
      .arc()
      .innerRadius(inner + 5)
      .outerRadius(r + 5);

    var pie = d3.pie().value(function (d) {
      return d.value;
    });

    var arcs = vis
      .selectAll("g.slice")
      .data(pie)
      .enter()
      .append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "slice")
      .on("mouseover", function (d) {
        d3.select(this)
          .select("path")
          .transition()
          .duration(200)
          .attr("d", arcOver);

        textTop.text(d3.select(this).datum().data.label).attr("y", -10);
        textBottom
          .text(d3.select(this).datum().data.value.toFixed(2))
          .attr("y", 10);
      })
      .on("mouseout", function (d) {
        d3.select(this)
          .select("path")
          .transition()
          .duration(100)
          .attr("d", arc);

        textTop.text("Total Orders").attr("y", -10);
        textBottom.text(total.toFixed(2) + "m");
      });

    arcs
      .append("svg:path")
      .style("fill", function (d, i) {
        return color(i);
      })
      .attr("d", arc);

    var legend = svg
      .append("g")
      .classed('legend', true)
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("g")

      .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
        return "translate(" + (r + 20) + "," + ((i - data.length / 2) * 45 + 10) + ")";
      });

    legend
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", 6)
      .attr('cy', 10)
      .attr('cx', 8)
      .style("fill", function (d, i) {
        return color(i);
      });

    legend
      .append("text")
      .attr("x", 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("fill", "rgb(112,112,112)")
      .style('font-weight', 'bold')
      .text(function (d) {
        return d.label;
      });
    legend
      .append("text")
      .attr("x", 24)
      .attr("y", 30)
      .attr("fill", "rgb(112,112,112)")
      .text(d => `${d.value} orders`);
```

```css
.legend text {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart-1" />
```

Here is a forked Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-with-d3js-charts-fw9rkv

Comment: Hey Michael Rovinsky!! Thanks a lot for help. This is perfect. 